# How to upgrade chef server 11 to 12

Tags: chef-infra, devops, aws-opsworks

I would like to upgrade my chef server 11 to 12 latest version, server is in AWS, how to prepare server and role back steps if any thing went wrong. I have gone trough below link from chef docs. If any one upgrade chef server, could you please share steps.
https://docs.chef.io/upgrade_server.html

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to read the documentation:
    https://docs.chef.io/upgrade_server.html

Secondly, in order for you to backup the Chef data also they have wrote good documentation on how to do this, which could be found at: https://docs.chef.io/server_backup_restore.html

Presumably your cookbooks are already in a VCM (version control management) such as GIT therefore they are already backed up and versioned.

Thirdly, you will have to backup your roles and environments which I believe you would find everything that you need on the links provided.

Comment: thanks for responded, I will  do it on test servers before doing

Comment: you're welcome :) and totally, you should always backup and test ;) also if this works well for you don't forget to accept the answer :)